# Reading arbitrary length strings in C

Tags: c, string, memory

I've attempted to write a C program to read a string and display it back to the user. I've tested it with a lot of input and it seems to work properly. The thing is that I'm not sure whether or not the `c != EOF` condition is necessary inside the while expression, and since by definition, the size of a char is 1 byte, maybe I can remove the `sizeof(char)` expressions inside the `malloc` and `realloc` statements, but I'm not sure about this.

Here's the program, also, I manually added a null terminating character to the string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *str = malloc(sizeof(char));

    if (!str)
        return 1;

    char c;
    char *reallocStr;
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t buf = 1;

    printf("Enter some text: ");

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        if (len == buf) {
            buf *= 2;

            reallocStr = realloc(str, buf * sizeof(char));

            if (!reallocStr)
                return 1;

            str = reallocStr;
        }

        str[len++] = c;
    }

    str[len] = '\0';

    printf("You entered: %s\n", str);

    free(str);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is this any better than using `fgets`?

Comment: Allocating a single byte is ridiculous, you can't fit *any* useful string data in there. Start with something like `8` at least.

Comment: You have an overflow bug here since you test `len == buf` *before* incrementing. You can't write to `str[buf]`, but you do on `str[len] = 0`. This should probably be `if (len + 1 == buf)` which can be read as "if a write would overflow..."

Comment: Aside: for a binary file it would be necessary to change `char c;` to `int c;` The library functions do not return a `char` type, so please get into the habit.

Comment: @tadman how would I use `fgets` in this case since a parameter it requires is the size of the string?

Comment: You take a guess. If you guess wrong `fgets` will let you know it couldn't finish, so you can resize and try again, re-open the file and restart the process with a bigger buffer. If you're dealing with data that can fit in memory, just read the whole file and split it there. Unless you're dealing with gigantic files that cannot possibly fit, just read the whole thing and be done with it, or use memory mapped files.

Comment: @tadman *re-open* yes, and ask the user politely to re-type what he has just typed and you have thrown away.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. You can rewind the stream, it's not a big deal. My usual method is read the whole thing in, where there's a presumption it will fit in memory, or at least you can have a reasonably ridiculous line limit for `fgets` so it if fails it's a user error.

Comment: @tadman rewinding the stream is problematic if the stream is not a regular file.  But there's no need to do that.  If `fgets` doesn't get a full line, realloc the buffer and do another `fgets` at the end of the previous buffer.  (eg, append to the previous read).  Keep doing that until you get a full line.  It's really no different than calling getchar in a loop.  But there's no real advantage to using `fgets` instead of `getchar`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I normally do just that, but upon reading the `fgets` documentation in more detail, it seems like there's no guarantee the buffer is coherent on a failed read due to space limits. `fgets` should be faster than single character reads as `f`-series functions are buffered.

Comment: @tadman Did you ever try to rewind a terminal? How do you imagine it should work?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. If you want an argument, go to Reddit, please. I've enumerated several alternatives there that do not involve rewinding, and rewinding is fine for *files*.

Comment: @WeatherVane With [or a binary file it would be necessary to change char c; to int c;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73240276/reading-arbitrary-length-strings-in-c/73242317#comment129347451_73240276) is true, yet the issue also applies to _text_ files.  Has `char` been an _unsigned char_, loop would not have ended on `EOF`. in binary or text mode. Text streams are not required by C to end with a `'\n'`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, yes but here it wasn't necessary (the cause of the problem). I did say *please get into the habit*.

Comment: @WeatherVane  I assert it is necessary to prevent a possible infinite loop.  The buffer issue is one of several issues.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, it is necessary, as we know. I was just pointing out that it *would* have been a problem. As opposed to a potential problem. My original comment was not wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have a buffer overflow in your code, so you would need to fix that at the very least.   To answer your specific questions, `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 (dictated by the c99 spec), so you don't need to multiply by `sizeof(char)`.   It's good practice to check for `EOF` as if your input is coming from an alternate source that has no newline, you don't die (so if someone for example did `printf %s hello | yourprogram` from a bash prompt, you wouldn't die).

Comment: Thanks for answering my specific questions! I've fixed the buffer overflow by changing `if (len == buf)` to `if (len + 1 == buf)`.

Answer (score 0):

Problems include

**Buffer overflow**

[@HardcoreHenry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240498/2410359)

**Incorrect type**

`getchar()` reruns an `int` with the values [0..UCHAR_MAX] and the negative: `EOF`.  These 257 different values lose distinctiveness when saved as a `char`.  Possible outcomes: infinite loop or premature loop end.  Instead:

```
// char c;
int c;
```

**Advanced: Arbitrary length**

For *very* long lines `buf *= 2;` overflows when `buf` is `SIZE_MAX/2 + 1`.  An alterative to growing in steps of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16,..., consider 1, 3, 7, 15, ....  That way code can handle strings up to `SIZE_MAX`.

**Advanced: Reading `'\0'`**

Although uncommon, possible to read in a *null character*.  Then `printf("You entered: %s\n", str);` will only print to that *null character* and not to the end of input.

To print all, take advantage that code knows the length.

```
printf("You entered: ");
fwrite(str, len, 1, stdout);
printf("\n");
```

To be clear, text input here is *not* reading of *strings*, but of reading of *lines*.  That input is saved and converted to a *string* by appending a *null character*.  Reading a `'\0'` complicates things, but something robust code handles.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've learned many things from your answer. I've changed the type of `c` and I now start with a buffer of 2, but I now reallocate with a size of `buf - 1`, since I believe that if an overflow occurs, the value of `buf` will be 0, so 0 - 1 in size would be `SIZE_MAX`. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Instead of starting with `buf == 2`, remain with `buf = 1` and try `if (len + 1 == buf) {  buf = buf * 2 + 1; ... }`

Comment: I'm a bit rusty with my recurrence solving, but you're right! That makes everything so much better. Thanks for the feedback!